# Conditional choose Provider Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 3 PaymentProvider and in my `config/app.php` 3 lines with code for selecting the Provider like this:

```
xxx\laravel\payment\mollie\Provider::class,
//xxx\laravel\payment\omnikassa\Provider::class,
//xxx\laravel\payment\ingenico\Provider::class,
```

There is a way to do it with my .env file, but is it possible to dynamically select the right Provider?

Comment: can you  use interface with service container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try some thing like this;

Just assign returning array to a variable and then set the conditions on the base of env

```
$arr = [
    'providers' => [
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class
    ],
];

if(env('provider') == 'local'){
    array_push($arr['providers'], App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class);
}


return $arr;
```

Comment: Nice solution, 'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class' is without '.